# Problema con fechas en C# y MariaDB XAMPP

Tags: c#

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con Xamarin.Forms que se comunica con mi API REST hecha en Node.js y esta se comunica con mi base de datos en phpmyadmin. (Todo el desarrollo esta en local).

El problema que tengo es que cuando envio los datos JSON y miro con un `console.log()` lo que se envia veo que la fecha es correcta.

**2018-05-16T00:00:00+02:00**

Luego al comprobar desde phpymyadmin que los datos se hayan guardado bien veo que pone que es un día menos. (El campo es un DATE).

También cuando quiero recibir los datos desde mi base de datos antes de que me los envie he comprobado con un `console.log()` y me devuelve este formato de fecha con un día menos:

**2018-05-15T22:00:00.000Z**

Cuando deserializo el JSON y lo veo con Debug.WriteLine(fecha) me muestra este otro tipo de fecha:

**5/15/2018 10:00:00 PM +00:00**

- He comprobado desde Visual Studio con Debug.WriteLine(fecha.Kind) al enviar y recibir para saber si son UTC o Local y en ambos casos son Local.
- He configurado en Node.js el timezone con process.env.TZ = 'Europe/Madrid'.
- He cambiado la timezone de php.ini por si acaso y también MySQL desde consola he probado estas sentencias:

---

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT NOW();
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2018-05-16 22:40:27 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
+--------------------+---------------------+
| @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| SYSTEM             | SYSTEM              |
+--------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: ¿En qué zona horaria se encuentra el móvil donde accedes a la API?

Comment: Mi móvil utiliza el horario de España GMT+1 pero ahora es GMT+2 por el cambio de horario de verano.

Comment: Has probado a fijar la zona en el servidor mariadb? mira [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-g11n-excerpt/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html)

Comment: Siguiendo la documentación del enlace he configurado el timezone con `SET GLOBAL time_zone = "Europe/Madrid;`, he comprobado que se ha guardado pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema.

Answer (score 1):

### **Explicación**

Hay un +2 que define la zona horaria.

```
2018-05-16T00:00:00+02:00
```

Aquí no tiene ese +2 pero tiene una "Z" al final.

```
2018-05-15T22:00:00.000Z
```

Esa "Z" significa que tiene "Zero Offset", en otras palabras, es la hora universal. Si la hora está en UTC, decir "09:30 UTC" es lo mismo que "09:30Z" or "0930Z". "14:45:15 UTC" sería "14:45:15Z" o "144515Z".

En C#, al ejecutar:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o"));  
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("o"));
```

Nos da como resultado:

```
2018-05-16T21:06:58.4259227Z
2018-05-16T14:06:58.4269282-07:00
```

Ese 7Z o -07 indica la franja horaria donde se está ejecutando este código, en este caso indica:

```
Time in US Mountain Standard Time.
```

### **Una vez explicado esto, vamos por tu caso:**

```
2018-05-16T00:00:00+02:00
```

Tenemos 2 horas adelantadas, lo que significa que la hora del registro en modo "universal" fue en:

```
2018-05-15T22:00:00.000Z
```

Y al momento de deserializar sigue siendo la fecha universal, sólo que en otro formato. (22 horas == 10pm) && (Oz == +00)

```
5/15/2018 10:00:00 PM +00:00
```

### **Sugerencia**

Trabaja en horas universales y las conversiones las realizas en el cliente.

### **Referencia y lectura recomendada**

ISO 8601: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Gracias por la explicación, me ha servido de ayuda para entender los horarios. He probado mi app desde mi móvil y ordenador con el metodo `fecha.Date.ToUniversalTime()` para enviar y recibir pero sigue haciendome los mismos problemas.